# Showing temporal *.html page while loading the proper one

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I load a website to [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#on%28type.2C_listener%29) that provides some functionality. Unfortunately, it takes some time and for a few seconds, user actually see the previous site loaded to panel. It could lead to misunderstandings.

Is there a way to set a html page (for example with "loading" animation) that will be shown every time when browser load the proper page?

Comment: Yes I think this is easy can you share the code you are using right now so we can modify it to show temporal?

Comment: just initialize the panel with a html stored in your addon?

Comment: After some reaearch, I think the best way here will be simply destroying panel and create new one.